# Problems related to Zener Diodes to determine the ratio of transformer

Tags: transformer, zener, bridge-rectifier

I am having a problem which is related to a circuit as shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdD45z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I will give you more information about this circuit. V1 in this circuit is (220V/50Hz) and the transformer has no information about the ratio n1/n2. R1 is 200 Ohm as shown in the circuit but RL is unknown (Because I do not know how to clear the information of RL).

As operating, Uz1 = Uz2 = 4.25V and Iz1 = Iz2 = 2.5 mA.

My problem is to determine the ratio of transformer with these information. I found it really hard because I think there are not enough equations to calculate V2 (secondary voltage)

Comment: First step is to calculate what voltage you need at the output of the rectifier BR1. Then look up what the relation is between AC voltage at V2 (secondary winding) and the output of the bridge rectifier. This has to do with AC peak voltage and voltage drop across the diodes in the rectifier. Do note that there is **no smoothing capacitor** in your circuit. That means the voltage at R1 will have a "ripple" shape, it will not be DC! Once you know what V2 needs to be the transformer ratio can be calculated.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Hmm it's quite confusing because I find that you do not use anything which is related to Zener diodes and their information here and does the ripple shape affect the way to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm **assuming** that you can do the calculations needed to determine the voltage needed at R1. If you cannot then you need to get studying and learn how to solve that, maybe this helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYtebfx-yHc  If you also do not understand ripple then again you need to study and learn about rectifiers: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_6.html *there are not enough equations* OK, now **forget** about equations for a moment and **think** how the circuit works. If you understand how the circuit works, the equations become obvious.

Comment: Why are you not considering a voltage regulator instead of a zener diode? Nobody these days will use zeners in preference to a voltage regulator without a good reason.

Comment: I agree with Andyaka that this circuit isn't one you should be building as it is quite inefficient. I was assuming that this is just a **design exercise** to learn how to design it. If you need something that generates a stable voltage across a load, there are smarter solutions.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Actually your video you send me does not help me much. Instead of giving me more hints, I really appreciate if you can give me a model answer, which is more helpful to me

Comment: I'm not going to do "hand holding" and solve the problem for you. If my hints don't help enough then, like I suggested, you need to **study**. If you're not willing to learn how to do this yourself then you've come to the wrong site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be a homework or study question with no demonstration of effort to solve.